# Sql Basic Queries

Tags: sql

Good afternoon everyone,

I'm just learning my way around SQL and have run into a slight problem.

I am using the Northwind data base and can't seem to get two product name to appear at the same time.

The question is "Find the total value for all products except chai and chang".

I'm putting in Select: ProductName, (Unitsinstock*Unitprice) From: Products Where: ProductName <> 'Chai, Chang'

I can get one to come up, but can't figure out how to get both of them to appear.

Best regards

Comment: I even tried 'chai', 'chang'   what gives?!

Comment: Use `NOT IN` instead of `<>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT IN` for this instead of `<>`:

```
NOT IN ('Chai','Chang')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ...

```
Select ProductName, (Unitsinstock*Unitprice) From Products Where ProductName NOT IN ('Chai' , 'Chang')
```